# How to fix for-loop output in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I have 3 routers on my test lab environment, I'm trying to reach these routers and send some commands using `for-loop` and send output in the way I type/list them.

I have 3 1841 Cisco routers and running 12.4 IOS:

```
    multi_ip_addr = ['192.168.1.1', '192.168.2.1', '192.168.3.1']
    for ips in multi_ip_addr:
        pass
    len_ip_addr = len(multi_ip_addr)
    for len_ip in range(len_ip_addr):
        device = {'ip': ips, 
        'username': 'admin', 
        'password': 'password'}
        print(device)
```

My expected result is:

```
{'ip': '192.168.1.1', 'username': 'admin', 'password': 'password'} {'ip': '192.168.2.1', 'username': 'admin', 'password': 'password'} {'ip': '192.168.3.1', 'username': 'admin', 'password': 'password'}
```

however I am getting this output:

```
{'ip': '192.168.3.1', 'username': 'admin', 'password': 'password'} {'ip': '192.168.3.1', 'username': 'admin', 'password': 'password'} {'ip': '192.168.3.1', 'username': 'admin', 'password': 'password'}
```

Comment: `for len_ip in range(len):` That is an error.  `len` is a function. You can't call `range()` on a function.  Presumably you meant `range(len_ip_addr )`, but we can't tell for sure.  Please post your actual code.

Comment: you mean range(len_ip_addr) ?

Comment: sorry, I have edited my post. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: How does the output you get differ from what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
multi_ip_addr = ['192.168.1.1', '192.168.2.1', '192.168.3.1']
for ips in multi_ip_addr:
    device = {'ip':ips, 'username':'admin', 'password':'password'}
    print(device)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the item out of the list of IPs. Use the for loop for that, not a range:

```
for ip in multi_ip_addr:
    device = {
        'ip': ip,
        'username': 'admin',
        'password': 'password'
    }
    print(device)
```

The first for loop will overwrite the value of `ips` on each loop, so really by the end of the loop, `ips` equals the last value of `multi_ip_addr`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for ips in multi_ip_addr:
    pass
```

As this loop executes, `ips` takes on the value of each item in `multi_ip_addr`.  When the loop ends, `ips` retains the value of the last item.

In the next loop, you never change the value of `ips`, so it has the same value every time.

Answer (score 0):

Python determines context with indentation, so if you want to use your `ips` variable for each entry, you need to do it within the `for ips in multi_ip_addr` context (where you currently only have `pass`.) I might also change the name of `ips` to `ip` if I were you, just to make things clearer.

Here's how I would rewrite your loop:

```
template_dict = {'ip' : None, 'username' : 'admin', 'password' : 'password'}
multi_ip_addr = ['192.168.1.1', '192.168.2.1', '192.168.3.1']

for ip in multi_ip_addr:
    print(template_dict.update({'ip' : ip})
```

#### Comparison with JS:

Using `range(len(multi_ip_addr))` will give you a set of index values, but this is unnecessary for what you are trying to accomplish. If you're familiar with JavaScript: the default `for` loop behavior in python is like the using the `for...of` pattern:

EX:

```
for (let i of <some_iterable>) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

would be equivalent to:

```
for i in <some_iterable>:
    print(i)
```